# Why do you need 15 reputation to upvote?

Tags: support, voting, privileges

I'm still a newbie on the askubuntu site, and what I experienced is that you need a reputation of 15 to upvote. I don't understand this.

Say you see a question that you would like to see answered or a problem you have too, and you would like to upvote but you can't. There are 2 alternatives to upvoting:

- give a "me too" answer -> undesirable
- ask the same question,  AND get 15 reputation for asking it (only if discovered not a duplicate?) -> undesirable

I understand that askubuntu wants quality questions and answers, but I don't see how this particular decision helps to achieve this. I would like to see this dropped, or can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be answered on the main meta site:

- [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-is-15-reputation-required-to-upvote)

Comment: Thanks! I am not so sure if I agree with the answer given there, but there is a point to it. The option to upvote on your own question/answer with multiple accounts didn't even occur to me...