# Why does Vote Up require 15 reputation?

Tags: discussion, community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do you need 15 reputation to upvote?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3591/why-do-you-need-15-reputation-to-upvote)

First, I’m totally new here Ubuntu/community.

I had a wifi problem and look for the answer here at ask Ubuntu and yes I found the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139168/dell-1390-wireless-bcm4311-ubuntu-12-04-no-wireless-icon-in-unity). Now I want to Vote Up the answer that’s help me out but then I saw I need to have a rep of 15. I'm new and can't help anyone now because I have zero experience so I can´t gain my rep. What is the exact reason for that?

Thanks.

Comment: This question should be asked in ubuntu meta...

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason is to limit people from registering accounts and voting themselves up.  Although this is technically still possible it would take more work.  I must say I am not basing this on anything I've read just a guess really.

The question has been asked over on Meta though check here [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-is-15-reputation-required-to-upvote)

Comment: Also because getting a 15 reputation is not very hard.